# Show and hide form no working propery with IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a simple js script shows and hide 2 forms variants.

```js
function show_form (item_form_id, item_desc_id, radio_item_id) {
/* hide all active */
var i=0;
for (; i < document.getElementsByClassName('active').length; i++ ) {
    active_item=document.getElementsByClassName('active')[i].style.display='none';
    }

/* show all unactive */
var a=0;
for (; a < document.getElementsByClassName('unactive').length; a++ ) {
    unactive_item=document.getElementsByClassName('unactive')[a].style.display='block';
    }

form_id=document.getElementById(item_form_id);
form_id.style.display='block';

desc_id=document.getElementById(item_desc_id);
desc_id.style.display='none';

radio_id=document.getElementById(radio_item_id);
radio_id.checked=true;
}
```

```css
.active {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr onClick="show_form('form_1','form_1_unactive','radio_item_1');">
    <td><div class="active" id="form_1"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="text 1"></div><div class="unactive" id="form_1_unactive">form_1</div></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="address_id" value="radio_1" id="radio_item_1"></td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="show_form('form_2','form_2_unactive','radio_item_2');">
    <td><div class="active" id="form_2"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="text 2"></div><div class="unactive" id="form_2_unactive">form_2</div></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="address_id" value="radio_2" id="radio_item_2"></td>
</tr></table>
```

It works properly with FF, Chrome, Opera but doesn't work properly in IE.
After select one form I can't put characters - cursor disapears.

I've tryed with css visibility and is the same - no cursor.
How to fix it or make in different way - show and hide forms ?

Comment: I recommend you to improve your HTML nesting structure and your naming logic(it's confusing).